# iOS NSURLSession waits for timeout if server doesn't exist

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

We use an NSURLSession to download data in the background, and have timeoutIntervalForResource defined so it will timeout if it takes too long, but if, for whatever reason, the source server doesn't exist then it still sits and waits.  Is there any way to get it to abort immediately, or 'ask' the NSURLSessionDownloadTask if anything has been downloaded yet?

Failing that, what would be the best way of performing a pre-check to ensure a server exists before trying to download data from it?

These servers may be out of our control so we can't place a small file to download to check availability.  The only file we may not about could be a sizeable video, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed ask the task about its status.  First, check the *response* property.  If that is nil, then you haven't gotten the first packet from the server.  If that is non-nil, use *countOfBytesExpectedToReceive* and *countOfBytesReceived* as needed to determine progress.

I should also note that these properties all support KVO, AFAIK.

You could also perform an explicit DNS lookup prior to scheduling the background request if you'd prefer, with the caveat that doing so would prevent you from scheduling something that might actually work if the user's Internet connection comes back online in the meantime.  :-)